# Добавить стрелочки к слайдеру

Tags: javascript, html

На данный момент слайдер работает через нажатия по миниатюрам картинок. Как допилить скрипт, чтобы картинки так же переключались стрелками? Вот код:

Классы стрелок - left1 и right1

```
// СЛАЙДЕР

$(document).ready(function(){

    function slider(item) {

        let path = item.attr('data-path');
        // let text = item.attr('value');

        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.demonstraition-img img').attr('src', path);
            // $('.low-energy-info').innerHTML = this.text
        }, 200);
    }

    $('body').on('click', '.material-img-item', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        let item = $(this);

        slider(item);
    });

});
```

Comment: этим кнокам добавь бекграунд :img

Comment: В смысле? Как это поможет?

Comment: у вас форматирование текста поплыло

Comment: так  добавьте.  здесь вряд ли за вас кто-то будет кодить. тут  вам помогут решить проблему. а с кодингом вам на upwork  или фрилансим.ру

Comment: а можно ваш hml и css сюда?